# Formatting a table via SQL database in Flask

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

Having a slight HTML formatting issue with my Flask app.  I'm trying to display a list of some data I have on court cases in a table, and the table has a heading of `Full Name, Type of Appeal Filed, County`.  however, I can't figure out how to properly combine HTML syntax and Flask syntax in order to have the table show up the way I want it to.  Here's my `views.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, g
from app import app
from .models import Individual_Criminal
from .forms import LoginForm

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = [i for i in Individual_Criminal.query.order_by('type_of_appeal desc').all()]
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user)
```

and `index.html`:

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>
      <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Type of Appeal</th>
      <th>County</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
    {% for u in user %}
      <td>{{ u.full_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ u.type_of_appeal}}</td>
      <td> {{ u.county }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**What I've tried so far:**
I've tried a number of variations on the `index.html` file since I'm pretty positive that's where it's going wrong.  Initially I had *all* of the content in the `{% for u in user %}` block, but that caused the table to be created each time with only one entry each, like so:
[image: attemptno1]

So, that was wrong.  Then, I tried moving the `<tbody>` line above the for loop, so the `index.html` looked like this:

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>
      <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Type of Appeal</th>
      <th>County</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    {% for u in user %}
      <tr>
      <td>{{ u.full_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ u.type_of_appeal}}</td>
      <td> {{ u.county }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

that produced something like this: [image: attemptno2]

so, still wrong.  My **expected output** is a table like it looks like in attemptno1, except just *one* table that contains all the info.  Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension in your view. Just assign the return value of `.all()` to `users`. That way you iterate over the results only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess based on how html tables are often constructed (one `tbody` and multiple `tr`s containing a fixed number of `td`s):

```
    {% for u in user %}
      <tr>
      <td>{{ u.full_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ u.type_of_appeal}}</td>
      <td> {{ u.county }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: perfect! I'll accept it as the answer as soon as it allows me. Thanks so much @jDo!